# Chrome float issue (Firefox & IE work fine)

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-float

I am having an issue with floats in Chrome. Everything looks fine in both Firefox and IE/Edge but as soon as you load it in Chrome, it doesn't render properly. This probably isn't the best method of doing it but I struggled to get this far.

I have a logo (logo.png) on the top left and then another image (right.png) on the top right. tight.png is twice the height as logo and I need it to sit above the content on the page but at the same vertical positioning of the logo.

```
.floatleft{
    background: url("images/logo.png") no-repeat scroll center top transparent;
    float: left;
    width: 641px;
    height: 76px;
    margin: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:1000;
}

.floatright{
    background: url("images/right.png") no-repeat scroll center top transparent;
    float: right;
    width: 255px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:1000;
}

<div class="floatleft">
<img src="images/logo.png">
<img class="floatright">
</div>
```

And I know the last part is especially ugly.

Comment: This could probably be done more cleanly.  First, don't use an img tag and assign it a background - that's semantically just wrong.  Use span, p, or div tag.  Second, make your outer div just a plain div, then put two elements INSIDE that div and assign the background images.  Third - is there a reason you are using background images instead of regular images?  Lastly - no need to float BOTH.  Just float the right one, and the left one will (probably) lay out just where you want it (on the left).

Comment: I'm also struggling to find out what you want. Aside from what @cale_b says, the second image is twice as high as the container it's in, why?

Comment: Can you make a (mock) screenshot of how you want the page to look?

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options to put this two divs, side-by-side:

- Floats
- Inline-block
- Flexbox

### Floats

It's worth noting that today, the use of floated elements for layout is getting more and more discouraged with the use of better alternatives.

```css
.container{
  width: 900px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
.container:after{
  content: " ";
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
}
.floatleft{
  float: left;
  width: 641px;
  height: 75px;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
.floatleft .img{
  width: 641px;
  height: 75px;
  background: url("http://placehold.it/641x75") no-repeat scroll center top transparent;
}
.floatright{
  float: right;
  width: 255px;
  height: 150px;
}
.floatright .img{
  width: 255px;
  height: 150px;
  background: url("http://placehold.it/255x150") no-repeat scroll center top transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="floatleft">
  <div class="img"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="floatright">
  <div class="img"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

### Inline-block

This is far more better than floats, because you have control over vertical position, using `vertical-align`. In the below snippet, I have put it to be `vertcial-align: middle` (you have two other options: `top` & `bottom`).

Regarding the browser compatibility, it is supported by IE8+

```css
.container{
  width: 900px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
.left{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 641px;
  height: 75px;
  margin-right: 4px;
}
.left .img{
  width: 641px;
  height: 75px;
  background: url("http://placehold.it/641x75") no-repeat scroll center top transparent;
}
.right{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 255px;
  height: 150px;
}
.right .img{
  width: 255px;
  height: 150px;
  background: url("http://placehold.it/255x150") no-repeat scroll center top transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="left">
  <div class="img"></div>
 </div><div class="right">
  <div class="img"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

### Flexbox

Flexible boxes, or flexbox, is a new layout mode in CSS3. Use of flexbox ensures that elements behave predictably when the page layout must accommodate different screen sizes and different display devices.

```css
.container{
  width: 900px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.left{
  width: 641px;
  height: 75px;
}
.left .img{
  width: 641px;
  height: 75px;
  background: url("http://placehold.it/641x75") no-repeat scroll center top transparent;
}
.right{
  width: 255px;
  height: 150px;
}
.right .img{
  width: 255px;
  height: 150px;
  background: url("http://placehold.it/255x150") no-repeat scroll center top transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="left">
  <div class="img"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="right">
  <div class="img"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```